# Hide controls based on selected value

Tags: angular-formly

For the sample code below (look [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/kYzezB?p=preview) for full plunker), how can I hide the "Driver's License Number" textbox if the selected value in the "Province/Territory" dropdown is not equal to 'ontario'? The current behaviour is to disable the "Driver's License Number" textbox. So I would like to hide the textbox rather than disable it.

```
(function() {

'use strict';

angular
    .module('formlyApp')
    .controller('MainController', MainController);

    function MainController(province) {

        var vm = this;

        // The model object that we reference
        // on the <formly-form> element in index.html
        vm.rental = {};


        // An array of our form fields with configuration
        // and options set. We make reference to this in
        // the 'fields' attribute on the <formly-form> element
        vm.rentalFields = [
            {
                key: 'first_name',
                type: 'input',
                templateOptions: {
                    type: 'text',
                    label: 'First Name',
                    placeholder: 'Enter your first name',
                    required: true
                }
            },
            {
                key: 'last_name',
                type: 'input',
                templateOptions: {
                    type: 'text',
                    label: 'Last Name',
                    placeholder: 'Enter your last name',
                    required: true
                }
            },
            {
                key: 'email',
                type: 'input',
                templateOptions: {
                    type: 'email',
                    label: 'Email address',
                    placeholder: 'Enter email',
                    required: true
                }
            },
            {
                key: 'under25',
                type: 'checkbox',
                templateOptions: {
                    label: 'Are you under 25?',
                },
                // Hide this field if we don't have
                // any valid input in the email field
                hideExpression: '!model.email'
            },
            {
                key: 'province',
                type: 'select',
                templateOptions: {
                    label: 'Province/Territory',
                    // Call our province service to get a list
                    // of provinces and territories
                    options: province.getProvinces()                
                },
                hideExpression: '!model.email'
            },
            {
                key: 'license',
                type: 'input',
                templateOptions: {
                    label: 'Driver\'s License Number',
                    placeholder: 'Enter your drivers license number'
                },
                hideExpression: "(!model.province == 'ontario')",
                validators: {
                    // Custom validator to check whether the driver's license
                    // number that the user enters is valid or not
                    driversLicense: function($viewValue, $modelValue, scope) {
                        var value = $modelValue || $viewValue;
                        if(value) {
                            // call the validateDriversLicense function
                            // which either returns true or false
                            // depending on whether the entry is valid
                            return validateDriversLicence(value)
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                key: 'insurance',
                type: 'input',
                templateOptions: {
                    label: 'Insurance Policy Number',
                    placeholder: 'Enter your insurance policy number'
                },
                hideExpression: '!model.under25 || !model.province',
            }

        ];

        // Tests the input based on a helpful regular expression
        // gratefully borrowed from jQuery.formance by Omar Shammas
        // https://github.com/omarshammas/jquery.formance
        function validateDriversLicence(value) {
            return /[A-Za-z]\d{4}[\s|\-]*\d{5}[\s|\-]*\d{5}$/.test(value);
        }

    }

})();
```

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance,

P.S: Fill the form the see the "Province/Territory" dropdown

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://plnkr.co/edit/97pINzLnz3W1HWmy9N0u?p=preview

Change

```
hideExpression: '!model.province'
```

To

```
hideExpression: 'model.province != "ontario"'
```